# How to identify pattern name after find()?

Tags: java, regex

How can I determine the pattern name per the following code:

```
   Matcher m;
   if( ((m = PATTERN_1.matcher(text)).find()) ||
       ((m = PATTERN_2.matcher(text)).find()) )
      {
         System.out.println("Pattern: " + m.patternName?);  // how can I determine the matched pattern?
         // i.e - "Pattern: PATTERN_1"

      }
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any feasible way. You'll just have to nest them.

Comment: does it have to be a single matcher? Can use `m` & `m2` for instance.

Comment: either or....but I just want the "name" of the pattern variable name (i.e. PATTERN_1  or PATTERN_2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`Matcher#pattern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#pattern%28%29) should work for you.

Consider this code:

```
Matcher m;
Pattern PATTERN_1=Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Pattern PATTERN_2=Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
String text="abc";
if( ((m = PATTERN_1.matcher(text)).find()) ||
    ((m = PATTERN_2.matcher(text)).find()) ) {
    System.out.println("PATTERN: " + m.pattern());
}

// prints: PATTERN: [a-z]+
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, how can I get the name of the pattern (i.e. PATTERN_1 or PATTERN_2)

Comment: `PATTERN_1` OR `PATTERN_2` are not the Strings they are variables. You can get the matched pattern regex from above API.